# Javascript todo list edit function

Tags: edit, todo

In the code below the function replaces the text content of all elements with the class "todos" with the value entered in the input field with the id "myinput". I want it to replace only  that particular element

```
const target = document.getElementsByClassName("fa fa-edit");
const sumbitBtn = document.getElementById("submit");

var arrayform = Array.from(target) //creats an array of the target 
arrayform.forEach((e) => { // can access each of the edit icons sort of like for loop

e.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("myinput").focus()
    const myinput = document.getElementById("myinput");
    let currentValue = e.parentElement.previousElementSibling.textContent;
    let currentElement=e.parentElement.previousElementSibling
    myinput.value = currentValue;
     let inputtextValue= myinput.value
     sumbitBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        let replace=document.getElementsByClassName("todos");
        let replacearray = Array.from(replace)//creats an array of the replace
        replacearray.forEach((i) => {
             i.textContent = document.getElementById("myinput").value
    



     })
        
})

})

});
```

This code replaces all of the elements.

Comment: hi, may I know which element that you want to replace from "myinput" value?

Answer (score 0):

- Move sumbitBtn  decalration inside adlistner
- Use  insertAdjacentElement to add sumbitbtn after the current
  element

  const target = document.getElementsByClassName("fa fa-edit");

  ```
   var arrayform = Array.from(target);

   arrayform.forEach((e) => {
     e.addEventListener("click", function () {
       const myinput = document.getElementById("myinput");
       let currentValue = e.parentElement.previousElementSibling.textContent;
       let currentElement = e.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
       myinput.value = currentValue;

       let sumbitBtn = document.createElement("button");
       sumbitBtn.textContent = "Submit";
       sumbitBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
         currentElement.textContent = myinput.value;
       });

       currentElement.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", sumbitBtn);
     });
   });
  ```